# Is there a way to downgrade from Windows 10 Pro to Windows 10 Home without doing a fresh install of Windows?

Tags: windows-10

I tried several sites and even on YouTube to downgrade to Windows 10 Home Edition but haven’t find the good results. Everywhere I found is to do a fresh install of Windows. Is there any other way to downgrade from Pro to Home Edition?

Comment: Looking at the deleted answer & comment [needs high rep to see] - are you sure it's 'cracked'? Win10 is so easy to get for free I doubt anyone would bother to crack it. Are you sure it's not just an OEM license?

Comment: Yes I am sure it’s cracked

Comment: It’s possible that when you try to undo whatever the crack did, your Windows will be detected as non-genuine. It’s certainly not cool, but reinstalling is the way to go. You should have a backup anyway. This is the time to use it.

Comment: @VizitBanger - The only method that might work is to perform an in-place repair, but instead of installing Windows 10 Professional, you install Windows 10 Home.  However, I suspect Windows will not allow this to happen, and you will be blocked from doing this.   What more than likely will happen is you will perform the in-place repair and will be left with a Windows 10 Professional installation that cannot be activated (since you don't have a license for it).  **The simplest solution to your problem is to bite the bullet and just do a clean Windows 10 Home install.**

Answer (score 1):

Without downgrading, you could easily remove the features you want turned off by going to Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features On or Off.  If what you are looking to remove isn't available, there are registry hacks that can turn off unwanted features.

Comment: You can also change a couple entries in Regedit, but that's not enough: your Windows license is linked to a specific version of it. Either you downgrade legally via Settings, or you're stuck with your current copy. What makes you think your copy is cracked anyway? Strange behavior? A kmspico.exe process running in the background?

Comment: Bitlocker is not available in cracked version of pro

Comment: Removing optional Windows Features will not downgrade Windows 10 Professional to Windows 10 Home which is what the author wants to happen.

Comment: Yes I guess this is the only option I have. ll do a clean install